# floer homology and viterbo's theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact manifold.
In their paper "On the Floer Homology of Cotangent Bundles",  A. ABBONDANDOLO and M. SCHWARZ define the Floer homology of $T^*M$ by looking at 1-periodic Hamiltonian orbits on the space of smooth loops on $T^*M$ and show that the resulting Floer homology is isomorphic to the singular homology of free loop space $LM$.

However, some people define the Floer homology of $T^*M$ by looking at 1-periodic Hamiltonian orbits in the fixed homotopy class $h$, where

$$ h \in [S^1, T^*M]$$

My question is: By using the above definition, is it true that the resulting Floer homology is isomorphic to the singular homology of $L_h M$, where $L_h M$ is the space consists of
loops in the homotopy class $h$ ( hence it is just a subset of the free loop space $LM$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the Floer complex decomposes as a direct sum of over the *conjugacy classes* of $\pi_1(M)$, no?  Since the manifold on which we are doing infinite-dimensional Morse theory is of unbased, not based, loops.

In Theorem 3.1 of [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408280) version of the paper you refer to, the last assertion is:

> $\Theta$ is compatible with the splitting of the Floer and the Morse
>   complex into the subcomplexes corresponding to different conjugacy
>   classes of $\pi_1(M)$.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I see, hence there is indeed a version of Viterbo's theorem when defining the Floer homology of $T^*M$ by looking at the free loops in the conjugacy class of $\pi_1(T^*M)$. Thanks!